# Months in 21/22 for excel given start date and end date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If my year starts on 01/08/2021 and ends on 01/08/2022, what will my Months in 21/22 be if the project starts date is on 01/12/2021 and ends on 30/11/2024.

I have the following formula but it's not giving the current months:

```
=IFERROR(IF((DATEDIF("2021/7/31",D6,"M"))>12,12,(DATEDIF("2021/7/31",D6,"M"))),"0")
```

Comment: Hi, I think we need more information to better understand what you're trying to accomplish here. Could you add more clarification and context to your example to help us better understand the issue?

Comment: Start date: 01/12/2021 End date: 30/11/2024, months in 21/22 should be 8. Formula is giving me 12.  =IFERROR(IF((DATEDIF("2021/7/31",D6,"M"))>12,12,(DATEDIF("2021/7/31",D6,"M"))),"0")

Comment: @periukera - this makes sense to me (calendar year spans 01/01-31/12, financial years can span 01/04/xx- 30/03/xx+1, your project year spans 01/08/xx - 30/07/xx+1 - you want to know months during the calendar years '21-'22 - perhaps specifying 'calendar' would help others not sure).  Anyways, my soln. below. Ta

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98XcRqdNQ-D0P4s_Z?e=Kykf9j) refer:

[image: '21-'22]

*Note: for some reason 'datedif' is recognised by my version (Office 365 compatible) version of Excel - hence I'm using an alternative derivation for the round number of months (`=round(12/365.25(end date - start date, during '21-'22)`).  You can easily customise this to suit your needs re `'=datedif(start date, end date, "m")`' if you wish...*

**Correct derivation**

=ROUND(12/365.25*(MIN(DATE(2022,8,1),F8)-MAX(DATE(2021,8,1),F7)),0)

**Contribution in each (calendar) year**

- '22 yr: `1 month = max(start period, start proj. yr) = max(date(2021,12,01), date(2021,08,01))`
- '22 yr: `7 months = min(end period, end proj. yr) = min(date(2022,8,1),date(2024,11,30))`
- Total = `8 (= 1 + 7)`

General Formula for contribution in over any period (screenshot / [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98XcRqdNQ-D0P4s_Z?e=GaZ5sd) refer):

[image: Generalised formula - over yrs. [xx, yy]]

```
=ROUND(12/365.25*(MIN(DATE(E21,8,1),F8)-MAX(DATE(E20,8,1),F7)),0)
```